# Reading object from file - Java

Tags: java

So I got code:

```
 @Override
    public String toString()
    {

    return "Numer: "+this.arg1 +" Imie: "+this.arg2 +" Nazwisko: "+this.arg3 +" nr Telefonu: "+this.arg4;

}
```

Save obj to file:

```
public static boolean addObject(Object object) throws IOException
{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nazwaBazy, true)));
        pw.println(object.toString());
        pw.close();
        return true; 
}
```

Create object:

```
static void dodajKontakt(String imie, String nazwisko, String nrtelefonu)
{
    listaOsob.add(new Dane(imie, nazwisko, nrtelefonu, licznik));
    licznik = licznik+1;
}
```

and finally Reading from a file and saving to object...

public static boolean wczytajBaze(Object object) throws IOException
        {

```
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nazwaBazy));
            boolean IsGood = false;

                Path wiki_path = Paths.get(nazwaBazy);
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");


               try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nazwaBazy))) {
                    while (true) {
                        String line = reader.readLine();

                        if (line == null) {
                           break;
                        }
                    System.out.println(line);

                    listaOsob.add(new Dane(Dane.getImie(), Dane.getNazwisko(), Dane.getnrTelefonu(), Dane.getlicznik()));
                    }
                }
```

the problem is that

```
listaOsob.add(new Dane(Dane.getImie(), Dane.getNazwisko(), Dane.getnrTelefonu(), Dane.getlicznik()));
```

from Reading from file and saving to object isnt working... I know somehow I have to put toString on this maybe cuz it is Serializabled but still I am not sure how to do that...

Example content of the file database:

```
Numer: 1 Imie: Troll Nazwisko: Aaa nr Telefonu: 600600600
Numer: 2 Imie: Troll2 Nazwisko: Bbb nr Telefonu: 700700700
Numer: 3 Imie: Troll3 Nazwisko: Ccc nr Telefonu: 800800800
Numer: 4 Imie: Troll4 Nazwisko: Ddd nr Telefonu: 900900900
Numer: 5 Imie: Troll5 Nazwisko: Eee nr Telefonu: 101010101
Numer: 6 Imie: Troll6 Nazwisko: Fff nr Telefonu: 010101010
```

I need it to be saved into an Object (my arraylist of objects) everytime i launch the program..

Comment: It is a very fat trolling

Comment: what made you think so? I just started java so it might seem bad but its not trolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Reader/Writer, to serialize object use ObjectInput/OutputStream. Try something like

```
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.ser");
     ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
     oout.writeObject(object);
```

Similarly to read the object back, try something like

```
     // create an ObjectInputStream for the file we created before
     ObjectInputStream ois =
             new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
     System.out.println("" + (Object) ois.readObject());
```

Make sure, your Dane Class is Serializeable. Also instead of using Object, pass Dane to your method and use it.

Comment: `¬í sr Dane—«Q2µ«N  xp`  this is what is created in my file using this writing :(

public class Dane extends Osoba implements Serializable

`public static boolean addObject(Object object) throws IOException
    {
            //PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nazwaBazy, true)));
           // pw.println(object.toString());
          //  pw.close();
           // return true; 
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(nazwaBazy);
       ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
       oout.writeObject(object);
       return true;
    }`

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` are not for writing to and reading from text files. They write and read an object in a specific binary format.

Comment: Okay, it almost works now... but the problem is it always wirte in same line and I would like it to write line under line or something so I can get whole array list of my objects

Comment: @Jesper Thanks have changed it to ser file. I am not sure why it's been downvoted though.

Comment: Okay thanks to all of you I was able to finish that... Saving like in the post above, and reading whole array list at once... Thanks!